# Using psftp to upload and download files

Tags: file, ftp, get, sftp, put

Hello I am trying to upload and download files from my desktop to my server. Now after some search I did download psftp. I used to use filezilla earlier, but I cannot install it on my desktop due to a few reasons. Since psftp (similar to putty) is just an executable for file transfer.

So now after going through this link http://www.math.tamu.edu/~mpilant/math696/psftp.html. I understood that put and get are two commands I would use to download and upload files. Now when I logon to the server and say get filename, it actually is throwing back an error
`"local: unable to open filename"`. I tried that with other files too, and I end up getting the same error.

Am I making a mistake or is it a problem with this executable?

I did not find relevant tags for this topic, could somebody suggest me the right forum for this issue.

Comment: belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright sorry for  troubling you guys, my folder was locked down, so I did not have write access to the destination folder.

Comment: I would add that you need to set up your local working directory using [lcd](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-lcd) (local change directory) command.
By default it is set to "C:\Program Files\PuTTY" which requires administrator permissions to write.

Answer (score 12):

if you're starting psftp by double-clicking the .exe, it will have a local working directory of whatever folder/directory you'd started it in. Unless the file you're uploading is also in there, you'll have to use `lcd` (local change directory) to switch to that other directory:

```
 c:\this\and\that\psftp.exe   <---working directory of c:\this\and\that
 c:\upload\file\is\here\file.txt <--where you keep the file to upload

 c:\this\and\that> psftp
 psftp> lcd \upload\file\is\here
 psftp> put file.txt
```

should do the trick.

Comment: well I haven't tried put yet. I am trying get only. I am double clicking the psftp.exe file,  and then I am logging onto my remote server as open remoteServer, and then it asks me for a user login and password....after that I navigate to the location of my file. And I am doing a "get filename", and it gives me this "local: unable to open filename" error.

Comment: Do you have write permissions in the directory where you're trying to download into?

Comment: the permissions are -rw-rw-r-- me me filename, me should mean that I own the file right?

Comment: Ok the folder is owned by the administrator, but I am the owner of the files, can I still download the files?

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory itself? If you don't have write permissions on the directory, you won't be able to create new files, though you can control files of yours already in there.

Comment: permissions for the directory are 777 and owned by the admin.

Comment: Hmm. Should be ok then. Are there any funky characters in the filename that might not be valid on the local file system?

Comment: Well no the reason I was not able to get the file was because my desktop I believe was locked down for some reason. Now I have changed my directory using lcd and I can download files. But when I try to upload, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Then you'll have to check permissions. Do you have read permission on your system and write permissions on the remote one?

Comment: No I believe I had read on the desktop, while write on other folders. As soon as I changed my working directory using lcd, I am able to download files. Now the issue is I am unable to upload. When I use the put command, I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to fetch (non-existent) local files.  Posting the full trace of the session might help.